# Substituir "[" por [ usando sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Estou a tentar corrigir uns erros de formatação de um ficheiro e tenho como input:

```
"[""teste""]"
```

E queria obter um output do género:

```
["teste"]
```

já tentei este comando mas dá-me erro:

```
sed -i s/"["/[/g *.csv
sed -i s/"]"/]/g *.csv
```

O erro apresentado é o seguinte:

```
sed: -e expressão #1, caractere 7: Comando `s' inacabado (s/// - faltou delimitador)
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Está cheio de probleminhas na sua linha de código.

1. O argumento passado ao [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) está sendo interpretado pela [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), o que pode resultar em efeitos inesperados
2. `[` é o metacaracter de lista (ou lista ligada se usado em conjunção de `^`, e ele não está escapado
3. O mesmo para `]`

### Correção

```
sed 's/"\([][]\)"/\1/g'
```

Explicando:

1. O argumento está protegido contra qualquer interpretação da [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) pois está entre apóstrofos
2. `[][]` é a lista que inclui os caracteres `[` e `]`; isso é devido a uma sintaxe especial das listas, `]` pode ser colocado como primeiro caracter da lista que será interpretado assim, não como fechamento da lista, então `[]a]` seria a lista que contém `]` e `a`
3. `\(` é indicando a presença de um grupo; o [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) tradicional não interpreta `(` como metacaracter de grupo; também poderia ter ligado a interpretação expandida das expressões regulares, mas não lembro se é `-e` ou `-E`
4. `\)` é o fechamento do grupo
5. `\1` é o retrovisor, uso o que foi encontrado no grupo de número `1`, como só temos um único grupo, e esse grupo é composto da lista `[][]`, isso significa que é o caracter `[` ou o caracter `]`

---

Veja funcionando em:

```
DESKTOP-NLIG01H+Jefferson Quesado@DESKTOP-NLIG01H MINGW32 ~
$ echo '"[""teste""]"' | sed 's/"\([][]\)"/\1/g'
["teste"]
```

Print para provar o ponto:

[image: print para demonstração]

Comment: Estou em windows e o uso de ' não funciona, usei o comando que me sugeriu e o output foi o mesmo que o input

Comment: Mas você marcou [tag:bash], e o apóstrofo simplesmente funciona com bash. Independente de Windows ou não

Answer (score 0):

Teste ai

```
sed -e 's/^"\["/[/' -e 's/"]"$/]/' *.csv
```

Comment: Discordo só dos âncoras usados